# How to show row and column crosstab query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

```
accountName     ProductsTypes      ProductPrice        Total
bell account    Food Menu Category  29634              40634
bell account    SleepingRooms       9000               40634
bell account    SleepingRooms       2000               40634
```

I Just want to show the table in this form using PostgreSQL

```
accountName     Food Menu Category   SleepingRooms         Total
bell account    29634                   11000              40634
```

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, with different accountNames etc.

Comment: This gets asked every other day. Please do some research before asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+crosstab

Comment: I see only for int value and I have even tried with some other examples. Actually, I am working in slam data. Could you just write the sql for this one